# swift navigation bar title remove animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have added Page Control to the title of navigation bar from Interface Builder. When the view push/pop to the next view, the Page Control animates (as how normally title would animate).

How do i prevent the Page Control from animating?

I have something like this but it didn't work:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView?.removeMotionEffect(UIMotionEffect())
```

[image: page control as title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I need to create a new Page View Controller to manipulate the Page Control that I have placed on the navigation bar.

Instead of having multiple Page Control on each View Controller, I just have one Page Control on the first page.

And switch between View Controller using Page View Controller instead of doing push/pop.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { () -> Void in
        <#code#>
    }
```

Comment: I assume this goes to
`override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
}`
bud sadly I don't know the title view animation code